# Twitter prefilled message is allowed or not?

Tags: twitter

I have just found out that Facebook policy prevents pre-filled messages. What about twitter, I cant find such hard restriction on Twitter policy, is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Twitter Developer Rules](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms) ,
Section II Principles
1. Don't surprise users
B. Get users' permission before:
sending Tweets or other messages on their behalf. A user authenticating through your application does not constitute consent to send a message.

Comment: What does this mean? Like Facebook no pre-populated messages? Like I am making a game app so I want to include in share button Twitter something like "I scored %i in game" I can't do that? What about links to app store and links to twitter page? Is that allowed? 

The user can always delete those pre-populated messages if they want.