# Facebook/Twitter posts SHARE button confusion

Tags: ios, facebook, button, twitter, share

I've read on Facebook's guidelines with Share button for iOS Do's and Dont's.

Does Facebook not allow there to be a custom message by the developer when the user shares their Facebook post?

If I create the following post for example: "I just scored %i points". That %i would be depending on how many points user scored in game. Am I allowed to include this in Facebook SHARE button posts? I think Facebook said no, but I see a lot of game developers are doing it anyways.

So is it allowed or not? I think it's allowed for Twitter, uncertain for Facebook. Do you do it as a developer if you use a Facebook/Twitter SHARE button?

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *FACEBOOK = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


[FACEBOOK setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My new score is %li!", (long) HighScoreNumber]];

  [self presentViewController:FACEBOOK animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That´s not allowed on Facebook. All messages must be 100% user generated. You can read about that in the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ (2.3)

With the share buttons, it´s not even possible anyway. The only way to include a message would be to authorize a user with `publish_actions`, and you would not get that permission approved by Facebook for prefilling, so that way is impossible too.

Btw, just because other developers are doing it does not mean it´s allowed. They are most likely using an old v1.0 App, so it will stop working for them after April 2015 - that is when v1.0 will be removed and everyone needs to go through the review process with `publish_actions`.

About Twitter: [Twitter prefilled message is allowed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717608/twitter-prefilled-message-is-allowed-or-not)

Comment: I'm currently testing my game app and I made a test Facebook account. I made for testing purposes "I just scored %i points".  And I don't use publish_action. It works fine. So I can't do that? The message must be completely blank? Can I at least post a link to the app store that would take the user to my app or a link to my game's promotional Facebook page or is that also not allowed? Can I at least post those in Shared button to Facebook?

Comment: how exactly are you posting that without publish_actions?

Comment: and yes, the message must be 100% user generated, as you can read in the policy. that means you can´t add a link in the message. you can use a share button with your link, and the user can add a message in the popup.

Comment: I'd edited in my code above. How about Twitter, do they mind? In terms of pre-populated messages and my App store link?

Comment: i believe it´s no problem with twitter, but with facebook it´s definitely not allowed. they are very clear about that.